# Django: Search using SearchVector returns no results

Tags: django, postgresql, search

I'm trying to get search results by searching multiple fields. If I use django.db.models.Q - it works fine. But if I use django.contrib.postgres.search.SearchVector I get wrong results.

My requirements.txt file:

```
django==2.2.0
psycopg2==2.8
```

Relevant parts of my models.py file:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
```

My code:

```
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
>>> Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains='is') | Q(body__icontains='is')).count()
10
>>> Post.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('title','body')).filter(search='is').count()
0
```

I don't understand why am I getting no results with SearchVector.

Tried doing this:

```
>>> Post.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('title', 'body')).filter(search__icontains='is').count()
6
```

Better, but still less than Q.